# How to visible or invisible tab in FormTab Page

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

I create a FormTab Page and in some case I need to show or hide tab. I tried  `PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisibility` in RowSelected Event but It does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use VisibleExp property on tab item

Or use AllowSelect

Your choice

Updated: take a look to the ARDiscountEx using explore source code

```
public virtual Boolean? ShowListOfItems {get {...};}
```

Aspx AR209500
form:

```
<px:PXCheckBox SuppressLabel="True" ID="chkShowListOfItems" runat="server" DataField="showListOfItems" ></px:PXCheckBox>
```

tab item:

```
<px:PXTabItem Text="Items" BindingContext="DiscountForm" VisibleExp="DataControls[&quot;chkShowListOfItems&quot;].Value == true">
```